# Set GameMaker to Use Windowed Area

Tags: game-maker

How do you setup the UI like the guy in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XDcSXVUGsE&list=PLPRT_JORnIuo-DyoWbB7LBrhqlJnsltJq) has it? I can only maximize the windows or have them windowed, I'd like it to fill the main area of the window so the tools are along the border. Here's a [screenshot](http://puu.sh/ohzkP/02dbdad852.png) of what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` → `Preferences` → `General` → uncheck `Enable Pop Out Windows` option and restart GMS.